# Varnish 3.0 and Drupal 7, get registered user to always have non-cached content

Tags: proxies

I have issue with Varnish on Drupal 7 detailed here: http://drupal.org/node/1886218

Basically, what happens is:

1. User visits the certain page as anonymous, gets content served by Varnish Cache (OK)
2. Logs in
3. Clicks the link of the page that he visitied as anonymous previosly, but he gets cached page, instead of user-specific (that should not happen)
4. If he reloads page (f5), he gets backend served page, but if he clicks that link on the menu, he gets cached page.

It turns out that cached page was delivered by browser, not by Varnish; anyway, that should not happen, because user thinks he is logged out (I have user specific block in header).

How i can deliver such cache-control in header, so Registered users always get updated (not cached) content, even if they browsed site as anonymous before they have logged in ?

Thanks for help!

HTTP response:

```
The url we checked: www.mydomain.com
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache (removed from security)
X-Powered-By:   PHP(removed from security)
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires:    Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:  Tue, 15 Jan 2013 08:38:54 +0000
Cache-Control:  public, max-age=10800
ETag:   "1358239134-1"
Content-Language:   hr
X-Generator:    Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Link:   <http://www.mydomain.com/>; rel="canonical",<http://www.mydomain.com/>; rel="shortlink"
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 33254
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Date:   Tue, 15 Jan 2013 08:49:22 GMT
X-Varnish:  1420616326 1420614128
Age:    622
Via:    1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Varnish-Cache:    HIT
```

Comment: Can you post the HTTP request and response headers?

Comment: Question updated with http response, how could i print http request ?

Comment: In a typical Drupal/Varnish config you bypass caching if the session cookie is set. Anon users don't get a session cookie from D7 by default. Check your Varnish config to see if that code is present. It's generally a good idea to have this because it also defeats caching of form results.

Comment: Are you using [Varnish HTTP Accelerator Integration](https://drupal.org/project/varnish) module? If no, maybe you should at least give it a try. After all, it is designed do solve problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `Vary: Cookie` in addition to `Vary: Accept-Encoding`. You may add it in `vcl_deliver` using something like this:

```
if (resp.http.Vary !~ "Cookie") {
    set resp.http.Vary = resp.http.Vary + ", Cookie";
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "^,\s*", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the response Cache-Control headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

Comment: nice suggestion, i tried to add this to all pages via custom module hook, no luck for now.